# libGDX camera not translating

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have a camera in my GameStage class and am trying to translate the camera when the left or right arrow keys are pressed. When I press either key and print the camera x position it changes, but nothing moves (actors on screen stay in the same position). What am I doing wrong?

**Screen Render Method:**

```
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(255, 255, 255, 255);

    gameStage.update();
    gameStage.draw();
    gameStage.act(delta);
}
```

**Stage Code Involving the Camera:**

```
public GameStage() {
    super(new ScalingViewport(Scaling.stretch, Lib.WIDTH, Lib.HEIGHT, new OrthographicCamera(Lib.WIDTH, Lib.HEIGHT)));

    initCamera();

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
}

public void initCamera() {
    camera = new OrthographicCamera(Lib.WIDTH, Lib.HEIGHT);
    camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth / 2, camera.viewportHeight / 2, 0f);
    camera.update();
}

public void updateCamera() {
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.LEFT)) {
        camera.translate(-5, 0);
    } else if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.RIGHT)) {
        camera.translate(5, 0);
    }

    camera.update();
}

public void update() {
    updateCamera();
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: You have 2 cameras?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From you visible code I would say that the problem is you have two `camera`s. 
One is created when you are calling `super` constructor. And one created manually. Even if you are translating the `camera` you created, for rendering `batch` will use `stage`s `camera`.

Remove the `camera` you created and work only with `stage`s `camera`.